# Python child class with fewer attributes than parent

Tags: python

I'm a bit confused here. In two different scripts I've created a child class that has fewer attributes than its parent class. For some reason in one case the code works without issues and in the other I constantly get TypeErrors for missing positional arguments.

This code works without any issues:

```
class Restaurant:
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        self.name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine = cuisine_type
        self.number_served = 0

--SNIP--

class IceCreamStand(Restaurant):
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name):
        super().__init__(self,restaurant_name)
        self.name = restaurant_name
```

but this, which looks identical to me, constantly fails for some in the line `super().__init__(self, first_name)` saying that **init** is missing 2 additional positional arguments.

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, location, occupation):
        self.name = first_name
        self.surname = last_name
        self.location = location
        self.job = occupation
        self.login_attempts = 0

--SNIP--

class Privileges(User):
    def __init__(self, first_name):
        super().__init__(self, first_name)
        self.name = first_name
        self.privileges_admin = ('can add posts'
                           , "can edit other users' posts", 'can delete posts',
                           'can modify posts', 'can ban users')
        self.privileges_user = ('can add posts', 'can edit own posts')
```

Can anyone please explain why this happens?

Comment: you use `super().__init__()` in wrong way - you have to run it without `self`. In `Restaurant.__init__` you get `restaurant=self` and `cuisine_type=restaurant_name` - so you send two values and assign to wrong variables.

Comment: Thanks! This explains the issue. And I also now understand why the first piece of code still works. I've been assigning values incorrectly all along.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use super().func()

In my opinion, it mean you call the parent method.

Mean you should pass the same args in parent method.

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, location, occupation):
```

Like this:

```
class Privileges(User):
    def __init__(self, first_name):
        super().__init__(first_name, 'default', 'default', 'default')
```

Or:

```
class Privileges(User):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, location, occupation):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, location, occupation)
```

I am not very good at english. Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

You use `super().__init__()` in wrong way - you have to run it without `self`.

`Restaurant.__init__()` expects two values `restaurant_name, cuisine_type` (not three) and in `IceCreamStand.__init__()` using `super().__init__()` you send to `Restaurant.__init__()` two values `self` and `restaurant_name` - but they are assigned in different way that you expect

```
restaurant = self 
cuisine_type = restaurant_name
```

If in `Restaurant.__init__()` you add

```
print(restaurant_name, cuisine_type)
```

then you will see your mistake.

---

`User.__init__()` expects 4 values, not 5 - `first_name, last_name, location, occupation`. In `Privileges.__init__()` using `super().__init__()` you send 2 values to `User.__init__()` but it needs 2 values more and you get error message `"missing 2 additional positional arguments"`.